# how to refresh Nsmenuitem on Nsmenu after click statusmenu then button press from menuitems in objective c for Mac application

Tags: objective-c, menuitem, submenu

I am using https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1420/_index.html and  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/EnablingMenuItems.html to create menu items and implementation of validateUserInterfaceItem in a subclass of NSDocument.

My issue is I don't know how to refresh Nsmenuitem on Nsmenu after click statusmenu then button press from menuitems in objective c for Mac application.

Comment: This question was not properly asked.

Comment: @TheDictator Vote to close?